# How to connect and disconnect socket depending on specific routes in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to implement an online multiplayer game using socketio. So far, I have created a couple of routes including a home, login, and game page with their respective components. Here is my server side code for the socket.

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

//socket logic
io.on('connect', socket => {
  console.log('User Connected');
  console.log(socket.id);
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User Disconnected');
  });
});
```

When a socket connects, it should log "User Connected" and the id, and when it disconnects it should log "User Disconnected". On the frontend, I included the socket logic within the board component which renders on the route of "/board?room=id" for some room id. When this component is mounted, the socket connects. However, after I leave the page, the socket doesn't disconnect. Furthermore, when I go back to the board page, the console outputs "User Connected" again with a different id. Does this mean that there are multiple socket connections, and is there a way to disconnect the socket once I leave the page? Here is the client side socket code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { leaveRoom } from '../../../actions/game';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import queryString from 'query-string';

let socket;

const Board = ({ game, auth, leaveRoom, location }) => {
  const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:5000';
  //room info
  const [room, setRoom] = useState('');
  //determines redirect
  const [exit, setExit] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const { room } = queryString.parse(location.search);

    socket = io(ENDPOINT);

    setRoom(room);
    //When to redirect

    if (
      ((!game.inGame || room !== game.room._id) && !game.loading) ||
      !game.room
    ) {
      leaveRoom();
      setExit(true);
    }
  }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);

  if (exit) {
    return <Redirect to='/menu' />;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean that there are multiple socket connections,

Yes, if you call io() with same namespace multiple times, it will creates multiple connections. check https://socket.io/docs/client-api/

To disconnect when unmount, you need to return a cleanup function in useEffect.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    let socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    return ()=>{ 
     socket.disconnect(); 
    }
});
```

check https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#recap